# Shutdown Hyper- v virtual machine in c# using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I want to  close the virtual machine hyper v 2008 server using my C# application and then again restart after the intermediate process gets complete. I dont know how to use WMI in C#. Any Code snippet would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

here is something that looks like and answer to Your question:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylorb/archive/2008/05/21/hyper-v-wmi-using-powershell-part-4-and-negative-1.aspx

I recommend to call powershell - You can do this from remote server(control station).

**Stop it:**
Stop-VM -ComputerName name.of.hyper-v.server -Name name.of-vm
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848468.aspx

**Start it:**
Start-VM -ComputerName name.of.hyper-v.server -Name name.of-vm

ps. check the technet links for examples.